google sheets v4 API. how to add error bars to column chart?
I'm creating google spreadsheet and a chart inside following the sample code at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts
I did not find the properties inside BasicChartSpec https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#BasicChartSpec or inside https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#BasicChartSeries on how to enable Error Bars.
I'm using python to create spreadsheets.
Is showing "Error Bars" not yet supported from the API? Appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that Sheets API cannot set the error bars to the basic chart. So, I proposed a workaround as an answer for achieving your goal. Please confirm it. If my proposed workaround was not useful, I apologize.

I believe your goal is as follows.

You want to set the error bars to the basic chart on Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API with Python.

Issue and workaround:
In the current stage, it seems that there is no property for setting the error bar to the basic chart with Sheets API. So, unfortunately, the answer to your question Is showing "Error Bars" not yet supported from the API? is yes.
But, fortunately, when Google Apps Script is used, the error bars can be set to the basic chart. In this answer, I would like to propose a workaround for using Google Apps Script with Python.
The sample scripts of Google Apps Script and Python are as follows.
Usage:
1. Prepare Spreadsheet
Please prepare a Google Spreadsheet and open the script editor. And, please set your chart.
In this answer, I used a chart created by the request body from your provided URL https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts
.
And, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services. Ref
2. Google Apps Script
Please copy and paste the following sample script to the script editor.
function doGet(e) {
  if (!e) {
    console.error("No event object");
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("No event object");
  }
  let { spreadsheetId, sheetName, chartId } = e.parameter;
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  let chart;
  if (chartId) {
    chart = sheet.getCharts().find(c => c.getChartId() == chartId)
  } else {
    chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
    chartId = chart.getChartId();
  }
  const chartObj = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, { ranges: [sheetName], fields: "sheets(charts)" }).sheets[0].charts.find(c => c.chartId == chartId);
  if (!chartObj) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("No chart.");
  }
  const { series } = chartObj.spec.basicChart;
  const containerInfo = chart.getContainerInfo();
  const c = chart.modify();
  if (containerInfo.getAnchorColumn() == 0 && containerInfo.getAnchorRow() == 0) {
    c.setPosition(1, 1, 0, 0);
  }
  series.forEach((_, i) => c.setOption("series", { [i]: { errorBars: { errorType: "percent" } } }));
  sheet.updateChart(c.build());
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.");
}

3. Deploy Web Apps
The detailed information can be seen in the official document.
Please set this using the script editor.

On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
Please select "Me" for "Execute as".
Please select "Anyone" for "Who has access to the app:".

In this sample, as a simple approach, the request can be done without the access token.


Please click "Deploy" button.
On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "Test deployments".
Copy Web Apps URL. It's like https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec.

4. Testing
In order to test this, please use the following Python script. Please set your Web Apps URL to webAppsUrl. And, please set your Spreadsheet ID, sheet name, and chart ID to params. When chartId is used, the chart is selected with the chart ID. When chartId is not used, the 1st chart of the sheet is automatically used.
import requests

webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"
params = {
    "spreadsheetId": "###", // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
    "sheetName": "Sheet1", // Please set your sheet name.
    # "chartId": "###", // Please set your chart ID, if you want to use the chart ID.
}
res = requests.get(webAppsUrl, params=params)
print(res.text)

When this script is run, when the above Web Apps is correctly deployed, the error bars are set to the chart as follows.
From:

To:

Note:

This is a simple sample script. So, please modify this to your actual situation.

When you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.

You can see the details of this in my report "Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)".


References:

Web Apps
Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)

